# moderated mediation with lavaan

Tags: r, r-lavaan

I was looking at this example:
https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/163436/r-moderated-mediation-using-the-lavaan-package to make my own moderated mediation, but I get errors and I am not finding the solution.

my model is:

```
model <- '
#direct effects
mem ~ c*var1 + cw*interaction +b*var2
var2 ~ a*var1+aw*interaction
#covariates
mem ~ age+sex+iq
var1 ~ age+sex+iq
var 2 ~ age+sex+iq
#indirect effect
ab := a*b
#total effect
total := c+(a*b)
#conditional effects
ab1 := a*b+aw*b
total1 := a*b+c+cw'

fit <- sem(model, data=mydata, se="robust.huber.white", test="bootstrap",bootstrap=1000)
```

The error message I get is:

> Error in chol.default(S) :the leading minor of order 8 is not
>    positive definite
>     In addition: Warning message:
>    In lav_samplestats_from_data(lavdata = NULL, DataX = dataX, DataeXo =
>   dataeXo,:   lavaan WARNING: sample covariance can not be inverted

I did scale all variables beforehand, not sure if that is the issue?
Any thoughts?

Comment: This would be easiest to answer if you provide a dataset.  What's the simplest dataset (and the simplest model formula) that reproduces this error message?

Comment: @Hack-R OK, I voted, but for new users it's often helpful to prompt them on how to improve the question, and give them a little bit of time to fix it before closing.

Comment: I solved it, there was a very stupid typo in the one of the variable names. Weird error message though...